# How to fix quotation marks to ajax json? (correct stringify)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have JSON like below, how to make it correct with javascript or some php script? I think it should have quotation marks on arrays.

like

```
{ "1":[ {"id":"171113524", "title":"xxxx", "category":"4",
    { 1:[ {id:"171113524", title:"xxxx", category:"4",
     start:"20160913062500", stop:"20160913093000"} , {id:"171115415",
     title:"xxxx", category:"1",
     start:"20160913093000", stop:"20160913100000"} , {id:"171115421",
     title:"xxxx", category:"2", start:"20160913100000",
     stop:"20160913104702"} , {id:"171115471", title:"xxxx
     ", category:"6", start:"20160913104702",
     stop:"20160913110000"} , {id:"17111049", title:"xxxx",
     category:"4", start:"20160913110000", stop:"20160913110500"} ,
     {id:"17111335", title:"xxxx", category:"4",
     start:"20160913110500", stop:"20160913111200"} , {id:"17111354",
     title:"xxxx", category:"4",
     start:"20160913111200", stop:"20160913111900"}
```

My AJAX/Javascript is like below

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://domain/corsproxy?url=http://json.json/json.json",
    type: "GET",
    timeout: 3000,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(parse) {
        var strHtml = '';
        $.each(parse, function(key, value) {
            strHtml += ' <span class="location">' + value.title + '</span><br />';
        });

        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML =
            strHtml;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: is that the result of your json output? looks like it is not a valid json data

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the json using this regex:-

```
result = string.replace(/\s*\n*\\+/g, ''); // Removes the spaces 
result = result.replace(/([a-z0-9A-Z][^:"},]*)(?=\s*:)/g, '"$1"'); // Puts quotation marks around keynames of the object
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert an javascript object to a valid JSON string all you need is:

`JSON.stringify(yourObject)`
[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

So in your example:

```
var yourObject = { 1: [ {id:"171113524", title:"xxxx", category:"4",
start:"20160913062500", stop:"20160913093000"} , {id:"171115415",
title:"xxxx", category:"1",
start:"20160913093000", stop:"20160913100000"} , {id:"171115421",
title:"xxxx", category:"2", start:"20160913100000",
stop:"20160913104702"} , {id:"171115471", title:"xxxx", 
category:"6", start:"20160913104702",
stop:"20160913110000"} , {id:"17111049", title:"xxxx",
category:"4", start:"20160913110000", stop:"20160913110500"} ,
{id:"17111335", title:"xxxx", category:"4",
start:"20160913110500", stop:"20160913111200"} , {id:"17111354",
title:"xxxx", category:"4",
start:"20160913111200", stop:"20160913111900"} ] };


var yourJSON = JSON.stringify(yourObject);
console.log(yourJSON);


{"1":[{"id":"171113524","title":"xxxx","category":"4","start":"20160913062500",   "stop":"20160913093000"},{"id":"171115415","title":"xxxx","category":"1","start":"20160913093000","stop":"20160913100000"},{"id":"171115421","title":"xxxx","category":"2","start":"20160913100000","stop":"20160913104702"},{"id":"171115471","title":"xxxx","category":"6","start":"20160913104702","stop":"20160913110000"},{"id":"17111049","title":"xxxx","category":"4","start":"20160913110000","stop":"20160913110500"},{"id":"17111335","title":"xxxx","category":"4","start":"20160913110500","stop":"20160913111200"},{"id":"17111354","title":"xxxx","category":"4","start":"20160913111200","stop":"20160913111900"}]}"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JSON.stringify to convert it to json string.

```js
    $(function () {
        //define a json object
        var employee = { name: "Test Name", street: "Test Street", phone: "111 2222222" };

        //use JSON.stringify to convert it to json string
        var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(employee);
        $("#result").append('<p>json string: ' + jsonstring + '</p>');

        //convert json string to json object using JSON.parse function
        
        var jsonobject = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
        var info = '<ul><li>Name:' + jsonobject.name + '</li><li>Street:' + jsonobject.street + '</li><li>Phone:' + jsonobject.phone + '</li></ul>';

        $("#result").append('<p>json object:</p>');
        $("#result").append(info);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

See this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rqmk4sx5/

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by :

`var obJ = { "1":[ {"id":"171113524", "title":"xxxx", "category":"4",
    { 1:[ {id:"171113524", title:"xxxx", category:"4",
     start:"20160913062500", stop:"20160913093000"} , {id:"171115415",
     title:"xxxx", category:"1",
     start:"20160913093000", stop:"20160913100000"} , {id:"171115421",
     title:"xxxx", category:"2", start:"20160913100000",
     stop:"20160913104702"} , {id:"171115471", title:"xxxx
     ", category:"6", start:"20160913104702",
     stop:"20160913110000"} , {id:"17111049", title:"xxxx",
     category:"4", start:"20160913110000", stop:"20160913110500"} ,
     {id:"17111335", title:"xxxx", category:"4",
     start:"20160913110500", stop:"20160913111200"} , {id:"17111354",
     title:"xxxx", category:"4",
     start:"20160913111200", stop:"20160913111900"}`

`var newJson = JSON.stringify(obJ);
console.log(newJson);`